# talk to modbus device

Tags: linux, rhel, drivers, devices, serial-port

I currently have a minimal install of `Red Hat 6.5` running, on the machine I need to talk to a [modbus](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modbus) device. I am wondering what tools and drivers are needed on a linux machine to talk to a `modbus` device for the main purpose of reading?  I did see some on google and I'm interested if anyone has actual experience using different libraries?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a programming language to open a socket and roll-your-own library, using the [modbus spec](http://www.modbus.org/specs.php).  Otherwise you can use an existing library, I have no experience with any of them, but this looked promising:  http://libmodbus.org/documentation/

Comment: thanks, i did google but came up with so many results I wasn't sure if anyone had experience with any and if any has a major bug that makes it not ideal.

Comment: Excellent question.  I've never used any of the libraries, a company I work for is developing their own but I can't say I have any spectacular tips on that front either.  Good luck!

Comment: Thanks again! We are mostly avoiding the R&D with making our own library since there are only two at my job that can do that haha.

Comment: I'm actually using the VB.NET Version of the [Modbus Library at this site](http://www.modbusdriver.com/shop/index.php?cPath=38) for a project I'm currently working on.  It's finished and it's a paid library, but it will keep you from rolling your own.

Comment: This is actually also the official `yum package` used for modbus. If you do `yum search modbus` it says `libmodbus` as the only result, so must be a pretty good project then.